# Tracking anchors in div through jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, anchor

Is there a way i can track how many `<a href=""></a>` is in a specific div through jQuery ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `length` property:

```
$('div#specific a').length;
```

If you want to know how many anchors with empty *href* and *content* exist you can use `filter` method and `:empty` selector:

```
$('div#specific a:empty').filter(function(){
    return this.href === ""
}).length;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use length as well as size also do :

But length is preferred (http://api.jquery.com/length/)

```
$('a').length
$('a').size();
```

Note: the .length property is preferred because it does not have the overhead of a function call  (courtesy : http://api.jquery.com/size/ )